# Getting the parent attribute of an Excel xml with python lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I have an Excel XML file where I need to get the style ID of the elements where there is a cell of a determined color (interior).

I have this Excel xml, as example:

And it is the header of the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

And here what I need to access:

```
<Style ss:ID="s64">
   <Interior ss:Color="#00CC00" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
</Style>
```

I need to write a function where passing the color #00CC00 I get this element, and then I can access to its parent to get the ID.

I have tried with this code, and it is not valid. I guess I shoud use namespaces.

```
parser = et.parse(str(file))
color = parser.xpath("//interior[@ss:Color='#FFCC00'")
par = color.getparent()
print(par)
```

I would need that the code returns "s64".

However it is not valid code. What do I am missing?

**EDIT:** I want to edit my question and add some extra information, after looking for more information I've written this piece of code

```
def _find_color(self):
    """
    Find the color in the xml file and returns the attribute.
    """
    print('The folder is: ', self.path)
    nsd ={'Default':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet',
                'o': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office', 
                'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}
    if pathlib.Path(self.path).exists():
        for file in self.folder.glob('**/*.xml'):
            print('The file is ', file)
            parser = et.parse(str(file))
            color = parser.xpath("//style/interior[@ss:Color='#00CC00']",namespaces=nsd)
            print(color)
            #par = color.getparent()
            #print(par)
```

However it returns an empty list. So it does not find anything.

Adding the whole source part that I am interested to work with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
     <Author>Somebody</Author>
     <LastAuthor>Somebody</LastAuthor>
     <Created>2016-05-16T10:44:52Z</Created>
     <Company>SomeCompany</Company>
     <Version>12.00</Version>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
     <WindowHeight>9495</WindowHeight>
     <WindowWidth>20835</WindowWidth>
     <WindowTopX>240</WindowTopX>
     <WindowTopY>420</WindowTopY>
     <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
     <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
  </ExcelWorkbook>
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
      <Borders/>
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss"/>
      <Interior/>
      <NumberFormat/>
      <Protection/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s63">
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#FF0000" ss:Bold="1"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s64">
      <Interior ss:Color="#00CC00" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s65">
       <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#FF0000" ss:Bold="1"/>
     <Interior ss:Color="#44CF00" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
      </Style>
   </Styles>
```

I am not able to find the element based on the attribute using xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it can be done.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

NS = {"ss": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"}

tree = ET.parse("workbook.xml")
interior = tree.find("//ss:Style/ss:Interior[@ss:Color='#00CC00']", namespaces=NS)
print(interior.getparent().get("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}ID"))
```

Output:

```
s64
```

Comments:

- The `ss` prefix must be used on all elements.
- XML is case-sensitive (`Style` != `style`).
- When getting the value of the namespaced `ID` attribute, the URI (not the prefix), must be used.

Comment: It is not working. I get a None object. I think that it is because I did not truly created the tree.
If I add getroot() and I use the generated object with find: I got the error that I cannot use absolute path on element.
Also, can I create a dictionary with only the namespaces that I will use, in this case the one for "ss"?

Comment: I'm not sure what I can add. The code works for me. There is no need to add `getroot()`. "workbook.xml" in my answer is your XML from the question with the `</Workbook>` end tag added to make it well-formed. And yes, the NS dictionary only needs to include the namespaces that are actually used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for I finally found for a solution.
It looks like that one of the mistakes was that I was not generating the tree (I solved this with getroot() )
So my solution is:

```
def _find_color(self):
    """
    Find the color in the xml file and returns the attribute.
    """
    print('The folder is: ', self.path)
    nsd ={'Default':'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet',
                'o': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office', 
                'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}
    if pathlib.Path(self.path).exists():
        for file in self.folder.glob('**/*.xml'):
            print('The file is ', file)
            parser = et.parse(str(file))
            root=parser.getroot()
            color = root.xpath("//Default:Interior[@ss:Color='#FFCC00']",namespaces=nsd)
  print(color)
            for element in color:
                print('Tag: ', element.tag, 'Attribute: ', element.attrib)
                par_id= element.getparent().get("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}ID")
                print(par_id)
```

It returns s64.

For the part of getting the id of the parent I've used the solution that mzjn provided me. As I did know that I had to use the URI instead of the short name.